# Is $L^p$ isomorphic to $l^p$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

From the Fourier transform we see that $L^2([0,2\pi])$ is isometrically isomorphic to $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$.  Is this true for other spaces and values of $p$ besides $p=2$?  What about if we ask about isomorphisms that are not necessarily isometric?